# How to locate parent path node.js OS independent manner

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I want it portable across OSs

```
var path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'foo.bar'));
```

This code probably works only for Mac/Linux/Unix;

What is the universal manner to write this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct and easiest way would be:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'foo.bar');
```

But if you really want to write the separator manually, you would do it like this:

```
path.join(__dirname, '..' + path.sep + '..', 'foo.bar');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depend it on the OS by ask node for it.
But I think there are some more differences like Volumes (C:\) which elementary different un nix systems.

e.g.

```
var sSlash = (process.platform.match(/^win/))?'\\':'/';
var path = require("path"),
fs = require("fs");

fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, '..'+sSlash+'..', 'foo.bar'));
```